# Can emgu cv do everything that normal open CV can?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am thinking about switching from using the C++ version of Open CV to using the emgu CV wrapper so that I can use C# to communicate with another C# program.

However, are there any features of Open CV that are not available in emgu cv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some but these are far and few between. If you understand how to wrap the methods or are willing to learn then there are none. I suggest you form a list of the key methods you wish to use or are using and examine the EMGU documentation for there support (note that this is the last stable release and 2.4.9 is in beta testing).

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/Index.html

I'm happy to help go through them.

Although I'm sure you will come across a speed issue eventually so for anyone else interest and to save time. Opencv is quicker in execution it is c++ afterall. EMGUcv makes use of this speed however there is some lag since you are still working with C#. It will not be noticeable a majority of the time. C++ has the edge on C# with execution but C# helps in productivity (its quicker to develop with).

So before progressing make sure that your application is not speed dependant else transferring data in other method may be better such using FTP and a local server. It may even be more applicable to rewrite the c# program on C++.

Hope this helps,

Cheers,

Chris

Answer (score 2):

Most of algorithms and functions are wrapped but not all.
You should have a look  on what you want to do with it.

OpenCV dll are used by EMGU. EMGU it is "just" a wrapper so the processing time is almost the same. It just take some time for wrapping the object (which is very quick).